# Threading time in quiz game

Tags: python

How can I use a threading timer to get a countdown while waiting for the user to get input and if it is out of time, the next question auto pops up? Is it possible for me to stop threading immediately? Like if the user input and it stop counting

```
with open("question.txt", "r") as question_file:
    questions = question_file.read().splitlines()

with open("choice.txt", "r") as choice_file:
    choices = choice_file.read().splitlines()

for i in range(len(questions)):
    print("Question:", questions[i])
    print(choices[i])
    guess = input("Enter answer: ").upper()

    while guess not in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
        guess = input("Invalid input. Enter answer (A, B, C, D): ").upper()

    if guess == answers[i]:  # Compare with the correct answer for the current question
        score += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest approach since you might have to use global boolean variable `input_entered` to keep track if the user entered an input. When creating a timer thread, you can end the timer thread with SIGINT which will raise `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in the main thread which can then be catched and move on to the next question

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import signal
import os

input_entered = False

def timer(duration):
    global input_entered
    time_waited = 0
    while (not input_entered) and (time_waited < duration):
        time.sleep(1)
        time_waited += 1

    if not input_entered:
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

def main():
    global input_entered

    with open("question.txt", "r") as question_file:
        questions = question_file.read().splitlines()

    with open("choice.txt", "r") as choice_file:
        choices = choice_file.read().splitlines()

    # Sample answers
    answers = ['B', 'C', 'D']
    score = 0

    duration = 5 # wait 5 seconds
    for i in range(len(questions)):
        print("Question:", questions[i])
        print(choices[i])
        input_entered = False
        thread = Thread(target=timer, args=[duration])
        thread.start()

        try:
            guess = input("Enter answer: ").upper()

            while guess not in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
                guess = input("Invalid input. Enter answer (A, B, C, D): ").upper()

            if guess == answers[i]:  # Compare with the correct answer for the current question
                score += 1
            input_entered = True
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Time\'s up!')
        finally:        
            thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```